# How do I unlock new songs?

Tags: deemo

Sometimes I unlock a new song, sometimes i don't. But I couldn't find the reason behind it.

Are there specific requirements for each song, or is it generic? It depends on luck?

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition of naturally-unlocked songs through growing the tree, there are hidden songs such as (as of v1.5):

- Invite (2m tree)
- Run Go Run (4m tree)
- Electron (10m tree)
- Yawning Lion (12m tree)
- Pulse (15m tree)
- Magnolia (20m tree)
- Angelic Sphere (20m tree)
- Leviathan (20m tree)

In addition to the tree reaching a certain height, these songs must be unlocked by tapping a certain object in the game, or fulfilling another condition. You might want to try it by yourself first. It's kind of fun and satisfying when you find and unlock them by yourself.

From [Deemo Wikia](http://deemo.wikia.com/wiki/Hidden_Songs),

> **Invite**: 2m tree, found under the table in the Library
>
>  **Run Go Run**: 4m tree, found in the treasure chest in the Library
>
>  **Electron**: 10m tree, found when tapping the ship's wheel in the Attic
>
>  **Yawning Lion**: 12m tree, found in the broken glass in the Attic
>
>  **Pulse**: 15m tree, found when tapping the tree in the central piano room
>
>  **Magnolia**: Immediately unlocked after reaching 20m and watching the final credits
>
>  **Angelic Sphere** and **Leviathan**: 20m tree, immediately unlocked after playing any song and watching the cutscene "Leaves"

Answer (score 1):

When your tree grows to a certain height, it unlocks a new song. However, you are half correct. The more accurate you are on a song, the more your tree will grow, thus unlocking new songs faster.

Answer (score 1):

You're leaving out some songs:

- Yubikiri-Genman
- Untitled2
- Walking By The Sea
- Beyond The Stratus
- Sairai
- Entrance

There are a bunch of ways to unlock songs. Buying books is an obvious but you can also go to different areas of the house and click on stuff. Another way is to score high on songs played in hard mode. On most the songs I've scored in the 80's and 90's, even got some full combos on hard mode.

The above songs come after Saika, mixed in with the 8 songs the other guy wrote about. I'll return here if I unlock any new ones an let you know what I did to unlock em.